# USA tourist visa application for a student

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, applications

I am still a student but wanted to apply for a tourist visa, because my best friend wants me to be at her birthday. My childhood best friend's mom would be taking care of all the expenses; since I don't have any proof of income tax since I'm still a student, they will be the ones to cover my expenses. Am I allowed? They are now US citizens.

Comment: If you are not from a country that’s in the Visa Waiver Programme, before applying for a tourist visa make sure you read and understand all the eligibility and document requirements. Your residence and ties to your home country will be an important factor in the decision https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyone can apply for a visa. First, check whether you need one at all: if you're from a country that's in the Visa Waiver Program, you don't need a visa for short visits. If you do need a visa, you can find the application procedure from the website of the US embassy in your country. Make sure you fill in all the forms accurately and truthfully and follow all the instructions carefully and accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Tunisian citizenship.

In 2013 I had worker visa and I travelled to canada to work.

I had a permanent job (CAD $65K salary per year)

I had an apartment.

I filled all the required forms truthfully and accurately.
I applied in the US embassy in Ottawa (Canada) : Yet I got **refused** the visa : **It depends on the agent** that you will give your documents too. **Depends on his mood too**, the dude didn't even bother to check my work contract, pay-stubs or any other proof : DONT ARGUE, ANSWER THE QUESTIONS DONT ELABORATE

And **depends on the country of birth** too.

Got refused the visa for : not enough economic and family ties with Canada.
I applied again 1 month later ... got my Visa.

And I'm talking here about my personal experience.

Ps : Once you get refused the visa, and even if you get if afterwards , every time you try to enter the USA you will be redirected to the secondary check.

**Having the VISA in your passport doesn't guarantee the entry to the country** : if you have the visa ... make sure always to have proof of residency in your origin country and self sufficient financially and your phone fully charged.